# Select the countries with fewest number of tuples

Tags: sql, sql-server

At http://www.dofactory.com/sql/sandbox I'm experimenting with submitting my own SQL queries against their sample database to become better at SQL. What I want to do is to select all countries from Customer that have exactly the fewest number of tuples. Here is my query attempt:

```
SELECT a.Country
FROM [Customer] a, (SELECT COUNT(*) AS Tot
FROM [Customer]
GROUP BY Country) b
GROUP BY a.Country
HAVING COUNT(*) = MIN(b.Tot)
```

However, the website returns an empty table instead of the correct result which is (Ireland, Norway, Poland). The correct result is easily realized by grouping the table by country and using `COUNT(*)`, and then looking at the countries that have the smallest `COUNT(*)` value out of all `COUNT(*)` values. I would like some advice on how to generate the correct result without any assumptions about the table's data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do this using `SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES`:

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES c.Country
FROM Customer c
GROUP BY c.Country
ORDER BY COUNT(*) ASC;
```

Two notes:

- When using table aliases, make them abbreviations for the tables.  This makes the query much easier to follow.
- *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: What does the "TOP 1 WITH TIES c.Country" part state?

Comment: It says to look at the order by clause and return the first row it specifies.  Then keep returning rows while the `order by` keys are the same as the first row.

Comment: Is the ASC part relevant for returning the correct set of countries?

Comment: Sure, with DESC you'd get the countries with the most entries

Comment: But is it ordered in ascending order by default?

Comment: @MånsNilsson . . . You can leave out the `ASC`, but the `ORDER BY` is needed.

Answer (score 1):

Learned somtihing new(WITH TIES) from Gordon Linoff, again...

Here my solution without it...

```
Select a.Country from [Customer] a
group by a.Country
having count(*) =  (select min(b.Tot) from  (SELECT COUNT(*) AS Tot FROM [Customer] GROUP BY Country) b)
```

Comment: This solution is correct too, but it requires 3 SELECTs and several nested parentheses for the SELECTs and isn't the greatest in terms of code length.

Comment: I agree, Gordon's Solution is much better

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using sql 2012 then,

declare @Fewer int=2
;With CTE as
(
select c.*
,ROW_NUMBER()over(partition by countryid order by customerid)rn
from dbo.Customers C

)

select * from cte
where rn<=@Fewer